# How to use Dirichlet/Abel test to prove the series is not uniform convergent

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Summation from n = 0 to infinity fn(x) where $$f_n(x) = \frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^n}$$  and x is real is the series in question and I have to show it is convergent but not uniform convergent. I would appreciate help. Thank you.

Comment: You always need to mention a domain when asking about uniform convergence. When applicable Abel/Dirichlet is used to prove uniform convergence. Non-uniform convergence is generally proved by showing a contradiction to the definition or Cauchy criterion.

Comment: The series is uniformly convergent on any subset of $\mathbb{R}$ that excludes $0$ as a limit point, for example $[a,b]$ where $0 < a < b$. This follows from the Weierstrass test. See if you can show this and add above as an example of your own effort. Below I show how to demonstrate non-uniform convergence when it arises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The convergence is not uniformly convergent on a subset where $0$ is a limit point such as $(0,a)$.

Note that

$$\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^k} \right| \geqslant \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^k} \geqslant \frac{nx^2}{(1+x^2)^{2n}}, $$

and with $x = 1\sqrt{2n} \in (0,a)$ we have

$$\sup_{x \in (0,a)}\left|\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^k} \right| \geqslant \frac{1}{2\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)^{2n}}$$

Since the RHS converges to $1/(2e)\neq 0$ as $n \to \infty$, the Cauchy criterion for uniform convergence is violated.

Answer (score 0):

What you give is a *sequence*. Check your definition, the sequence's uniform convergence depends on the interval of $x$ considered.

Comment: Sorry, I forget to add it is summation of fn(x) from n=0 to infinity

Comment: Please review carefully, the following post: [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?r=SearchResults&s=2|138.1095).